# Open Source Libraries for OCR which gives output files as text, pdf, excel, vcf format

Tags: ocr

I am looking for an cross platform ocr library and my requirement is to parse the scanned images and extract the text in to txt,pdf,xls and vcf format files. I have used tesseract ocr to extract the text but it doesn't give excel and vcf formats. Is there any open source libraries available to achieve this ?

Library needed for C#.

Comment: For which programming language do you need this library?

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Bulrush , I need it for C# language.